# enum implementation inside interface - Java

Tags: java, interface, enums, enumeration

I have a question about putting a Java enum in the interface.
To make it clearer, please see the following code:

```
public interface Thing{
   public enum Number{
       one(1), two(2), three(3);
       private int value;
       private Number(int value) {
            this.value = value;
       }
       public int getValue(){
        return value;
       }
   }

   public Number getNumber();
   public void method2();
   ...
}
```

I know that an interface consists of methods with **empty bodies**. However, the enum I used here needs a constructor and a method to get an associated value. In this example, the proposed interface will not just consist of methods with empty bodies. Is this implementation allowed?

I am not sure if I should put the enum class inside the interface or the class that implements this interface.

If I put the enum in the class that implements this interface, then the method public Number getNumber() needs to return the type of enum, which would force me to import the enum in the interface.

Comment: An additional (conceptual) question. Assuming this can be done, suppose you have a class Impl implements Thing { ... }, and in some other class User, Thing thing = new Impl(...) and then you want Number n = thing.getNumber(); - How will class User know what is the definition of Number?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to have an `enum` declared inside an `interface`. In your situation the interface is just used as a namespace for the enum and nothing more. The interface is used normally wherever you use it.

Comment: I know it is ok to use enum inside an interface. But I also make a constructor and method inside enum that is inside interface. So is it still ok for interface definition?

Comment: can we have a working example for above scenario.im confused :( :(

Comment: Of course it is ok, anything that is contained inside the `enum` is part of it and not of the `interface`.

Answer (score 9):

Example for the Above Things are listed below :

```
public interface Currency {

  enum CurrencyType {
    RUPEE,
    DOLLAR,
    POUND
  }

  public void setCurrencyType(Currency.CurrencyType currencyVal);

}


public class Test {

  Currency.CurrencyType currencyTypeVal = null;

  private void doStuff() {
    setCurrencyType(Currency.CurrencyType.RUPEE);
    System.out.println("displaying: " + getCurrencyType().toString());
  }

  public Currency.CurrencyType getCurrencyType() {
    return currencyTypeVal;
  }

  public void setCurrencyType(Currency.CurrencyType currencyTypeValue) {
    currencyTypeVal = currencyTypeValue;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.doStuff();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, this is okay.

The interface does not contain any method bodies; instead, it contains what you refer to as "empty bodies" and more commonly known as *method signatures*.

It does not matter that the `enum` is inside the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is legal.  In a "real" situation Number would implement Thing, and Thing would probably have one or more empty methods.